# How to prove 120 degree rotations of a hexagon form a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let H={$\rho_{0}, \rho_{2}, \rho_{4}$}, a subgroup of D6, the group of symmetries.  Where $\rho_{0}$=identity permutation, $\rho_{2}$=(1,3,5)(2,4,6) and $\rho_{4}$=(1,5,3)(2,6,4)

Identity is easy to prove but I am curious how you would prove closure and inverse.

Also, how would you figure out all the cosets of this? For cosets we are basically trying to build D6 from H so is the point of it to find $\rho_{1}$, $\rho_{3}$, $\rho_{5}$ using our set H?  If not how would you approach it.

I've been stumped by this problem for a while so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, $H$ is a cyclic group generated by $\rho_2$. So your group can be written $$\langle \rho_2\rangle = \{\rho_2^0, \rho_2^1, \rho_2^2\} = \{\rho_0, \rho_2, \rho_4\}$$ under the group operation of composition.

In short, $H$ is isomorphic to the cyclic (hence abelian) group $\mathbb Z_3$. Now, how would you prove closure under the group operation and closure under taking inverses in $\mathbb Z_3$?

$H$ is closed under composition (no matter how many times you compose $\rho_2$ with itself, the composition will result in one of the three elements in $H$). And indeed, $\rho_2\circ\rho_4 = \rho_0 = \rho_4\circ\rho_2$, so that $\rho_4 = \rho_2^{-1}$ and $\rho_2 = \rho_4^{-1}$.

Comment: Okay I got the subgroup part.  I don't really understand how to find the cosets of H.  And would H turn out to be a normal subgroup of dihedral 6? Can you perhaps elaborate more?